# How to compare the datas from Website with Database

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have one scenario i.e., need to compare the values from Website with Database(MS Sql Table Values)

In my website having one datatable which is dynamic and the values changed based on Username.

I need to check whether the values present in datatable(website) should match with the Database.

Kindly let me know any ideas and code snippet for this.

Comment: Kindly first provide your code which is not working or anything you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript/Jquery that when a user change a value in datatable send a Ajax asyncron request to the java server and here check the values.
For example:

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'myUrl',
                data: JSON.stringify(myValues),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
            })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly I would load the data from MySQL -> Put it in Some POJO that mimics my datatable -> And preValidate the data -> put it in datatable.

Please put out some code which you have tried already.